# Question on the coefficients of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{496}$

Tags: number-theory

> Consider the expansion $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{496} = a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{1984}x^{1984}.$$
>   $\quad$ (a) Determine the greatest common divisor of the coefficients $a_3,a_8,a_{13},\ldots,a_{1983}$.
>
> $\quad$ (b) Prove that $10^{340} < a_{992} < 10^{347}$.

Is there an easier way to solve this and is there a formula for the multisection for just the sum of the coefficients and not including $x^k$?

I thought of using the Multisection formula to prove (a). That is, $$\sum_{k \equiv r \pmod{m}}a_kx^k = \dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{s=0}^{m-1} \epsilon^{-rs} f(\epsilon^s x)$$ where $\epsilon$ is a primitive $m$th root of unity and $\displaystyle f(x) = (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{496}$.

Thus we have $r = 3, m = 5$ and so \begin{align*}\sum_{k \equiv 3 \pmod{5}}a_kx^k &= \frac{1}{5} \sum_{s=0}^{4} w^{-3s} (1+w^s x+(w^{s}x)^2+(w^{s} x)^3+(w^{s}x)^4)^{496}\\&=\dfrac{1}{5}\sum_{s=0}^4 w^{-3s}\left(\dfrac{(w^s x)^{5}-1}{w^s x-1}\right)^{496}\\&= \dfrac{1}{5}\sum_{s=0}^4 w^{-3s} \left(\dfrac{x^{5}-1}{w^s x-1}\right)^{496}.\end{align*}

Comment: See also [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A005191).

Answer (score 5):

About point $(b)$, we may notice that $992=\frac{1984}{2}$, hence $a_{992}$ is the largest coefficient (we are dealing with palyndromic polynomials) and
$$ a_{992} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(e^{-2iz}+e^{-iz}+1+e^{iz}+e^{2iz}\right)^{496}\,dz $$
is a real integral [not so difficult to approximate](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2011f/saddle.pdf):
$$ a_{992} = \frac{5^{496}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1+2\cos(z)+2\cos(2z)}{5}\right)^{496}\,dz $$
gives:
$$ a_{992} \approx \frac{5^{496}}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-496z^2}\,dz = \frac{5^{496}}{8\sqrt{31\pi}}$$ 
so $a_{992}$ is between $10^{\color{red}{344}}$ and $10^{\color{red}{345}}$.

---

About point $(a)$, given $f(x)=\left(\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}\right)^{496}=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n$, by the discrete Fourier transform:

$$ \sum_{k\equiv 3\!\pmod{5}}\!\!\!a_k x^k = \frac{1}{5}\sum_{s=0}^{4}w^{-3s}\left(\frac{x^5-1}{w^s x-1}\right)^{496}=\frac{(x^5-1)^{496}}{5}\sum_{s=0}^{4}\frac{w^{2s}}{(w^s x-1)^{496}} $$
[so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)):
$$ \sum_{k\equiv 3\!\pmod{5}}\!\!\!a_k x^k =(1-x^5)^{496}\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{495+5j+3}{5j+3}x^{5j+3}.$$
If we have $g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}g_n x^n$, then $\frac{g(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}G_n x^n$, with $G_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}g_k$. The sequences $\{g_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ and $\{G_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ have the same greatest common divisor, hence in our case it is enough to find the greatest common divisor of the sequence
$$ \left\{\binom{495+5j+3}{495}\right\}_{j\geq 0}. $$
The $\gcd$ is preserved by the forward difference operator, and the $j$-th term of our sequence is a polynomial in $j$ with degree $495$, with leading term $C_{495}\cdot j^{495}$. The $\gcd$ of the whole sequence is so
$$ \gcd\left(C_{495},\binom{495+3}{495}\right) = \color{red}{2\cdot 31\cdot 71\cdot 83}=365366.$$

Comment: Is the following true? We have $$\sum_{k \equiv r \pmod{m}}a_k = \dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{s=0}^{m-1} \epsilon^{-ms} f(\epsilon^s)$$ where $\epsilon$ is a primitive $m$th root of unity and $\displaystyle f(x) = (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{496}$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: commonly known as Fourier discrete transform, yes. However, it is not so practical to work with the whole sum of the coefficients, better to work with forward differences.

Comment: It is different though because I have $\epsilon^{-ms}$.

Comment: @Puzzled417: oh, sorry, no, the exponent of $\epsilon$ must obviously depend on $r$: otherwise, the LHS depends on it and the RHS does not!

Comment: According to my formula $\dfrac{1}{5}\sum_{s=0}^4 w^{-3s} \left(\dfrac{x^{5s}-1}{(wx)^s-1}\right)^{496}$ the sum of the coefficients $a_3,a_8,\ldots,a_{1983}$ is zero. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @Puzzled417: $a_n$ is obviously non-negative and given by a polynomial with degree $495$ in $n$. I do not know how you applied the discrete Fourier transform and I do not see how your sum is related with my answer, I did not use the sum $a_3+\ldots+a_{1983}$ anywhere.

Comment: In your equation, $$\sum_{k\equiv 3\!\pmod{5}}\!\!\!a_k x^k = \frac{1}{5}\sum_{s=0}^{4}w^{-3s}\left(\frac{x^5-1}{wx-1}\right)^{496}.$$ Plug in $x = 1$ and we get zero. So does that mean the sum of the coefficients $a_3+a_8+\cdots+a_{1983} = 0$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: if we evaluate $(1-x^5)^m$ at $x=1$ we get zero, yes, but the other term is divergent at $x=1$ !!!

Comment: What other term is divergent? Do you mean $w^{-3s}$? Isn't multiplying by $0$ to the complex number formed just $0$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: $\frac{1}{w^{s}x-1}$ has a pole at $x=1$ for $s=0$.

Comment: And anyway, the sum of the coefficients $a_k$ with $k\equiv 3\pmod{5}$ of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{m}=\sum_{k\geq 0}a_k x^k$ has to be close to $5^{m-1}$, always by the discrete Fourier transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)

Comment: Also, how do you get $$\frac{(x^5-1)^{496}}{5}\sum_{s=0}^{4}\frac{w^{2s}}{(w^s x-1)^{496}} = (1-x^5)^{496}\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{495+5j+3}{5j+3}x^{5j+3}?$$

Comment: @Puzzled417: the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^m}$ is well-known and follows from stars and bars (combinatorics).

Comment: It's still not clear to me how that equality follows. How do they complex numbers disappear?

Comment: @Puzzled417: as they appear from an analytic function with real coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

(a) Firstly notice that $a_{1983} = 496$ since we have to choose one of the $496$ terms $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ to be $x^3$. Now we see that we have $5^{495}$ choices for each of the terms until we choose the last one. Since we want the exponents to add to $3$ modulo $5$, there is exactly one term in the last term to get $3$ modulo $5$. Thus, $\sum_{k \equiv 3 \pmod{5}}a_k = 5^{495}$. But $5 \nmid 496$ and so $\gcd(a_3,a_8,\ldots,a_{1983}) = 1$.

(b) Using a similar argument as in (a), $\sum_{k \equiv 2 \pmod{5}} a_k = 5^{495}$. Thus, since the coefficients $a_i > 0$, we have $a_{992} < 5^{495}$. Then since $5 < 10^{0.7}$, we see that $a_{992} < 10^{346.5}$.Now, we first want to show that $a_{992} = \max\{a_i \mid i \in \{0,1,\ldots,1984\}\}$ and so we first notice that since $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ is a palindromic polynomial, so is $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{496}$. Then it is sufficient to prove the following lemma.

**Lemma.** *If $(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)^n = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_{4n}x^{4n}$ for some positive integer $n \geq 2$, then $a_0 < a_1 < \cdots < a_{2n}$.*

*Proof.* We prove the result by induction on $n$. For $n = 2$ we have 
$$(1 + x + \cdots + x^4)^2 = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4 + 4x^5 + 3x^6 + 2x^7 + x^8$$ and $a_0 < a_1 < \cdots < a_{4}$. Now suppose $$(1 + x + \cdots + x^4)^n = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_{4n}x^{4n}$$ with $a_0 < a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_{2n}$ and $$(1 + x + \cdots + x^4)^{n+1} = b_0 + b_1x + \cdots + b_{4n+4}x^{4n+4}.$$ Then since $$(1 + x + \cdots + x^4)^{n+1} = (1+x+\cdots + x^4)^n\cdot(1+x+\cdots +x^4)$$ and so \begin{align*}
b_i &= a_i + a_{i-1} + a_{i-2} + a_{i-3} + a_{i-4}\quad \text{for}\quad 4\leq i \leq 2n + 2\\
b_3 &= a_3 + a_2 + a_1 + a_0 \\
b_2 &= a_2 + a_1 + a_0 \\
b_1 &= a_1 + a_0 \\
b_0 &= a_0.
\end{align*}
Then since $a_i > 0$ we see that $b_0 < b_1 < b_2 < b_3 < b_4$. For $4 < i \leq 2n$, we have $$b_{i} - b_{i-1} = a_i - a_{i-5} > 0$$ by assumption. Moreover, we have $$b_{2n + 1} - b_{2n} = a_{2n+1} - a_{2n-4} = a_{2n-1} - a_{2n-4} > 0$$ and $$b_{2n + 2} - b_{2n+1} = a_{2n + 2} - a_{2n - 3} = a_{2n - 2} - a_{2n - 3} > 0,$$ since $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{496}$ is palindromic, completing the induction. $\square$

Now since $a_{992}$ is the maximum coefficient we see that $\dfrac{5^{496}}{1985} < a_{992}$ and it remains to prove that $10^{340} < \dfrac{5^{496}}{1985}$. This inequality is equivalent to $$2^{340} < \dfrac{5^{496-340}}{5 \cdot 397}=\dfrac{5^{155}}{397}$$ and $$397\cdot 2^{340} < 5^{155}.$$ Since $$397 < 1024=2^{10}$$ it is sufficient to prove that $$2^{350} < 5^{155}.$$ But this is equivalent to proving that $$2^{70} < 5 \cdot 5^{30}$$ and thus to $$5 > \left(\frac{2^7}{5^3}\right)^{10}=(1.024)^{10}.$$ Finally, $$(1.024)^{10} < (1.1)^{10} = (1.21)^5 < 1.3 (1.3)^4 < 1.3 (1.7)^2 = 3.757 < 5.$$

Answer (score 0):

The best prove is to deduce it exactly (just keep expanding brackets, that's tedious but duable):
$
a_{992}=61891934898586694757127096794241251770149317537060808781144881413603480491
24918357373293798914010206975822256711298898509033399713925282196435961001118646
50955624281976370104666002377445226707608416610042892219490874678682012497086475
04760953092185332340694544922169151358811534533683807953108052908377292793047440
8481763742091932486745302791125
$
which is roughly
$$
6.189193489858669*10^{344}
$$