# Polynomials and mulinomial coefficients

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, multinomial-coefficients

Let it be $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{496}=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_{1984}x^{1984}.$$
Find $$\gcd(a_3,a_8,...,a_{1983})$$
I know the Leibniz Theorem, so all coefficients are of the form
$$\frac{496!}{a!b!c!d!e!}1^a\cdot x^b\cdot x^{2c}\cdot x^{3d}\cdot x^{4e}$$ and $a+b+c+d+e=496$, $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb N$
So, if $d$ is the $\gcd$ of these numbers, $$d\mid\sum_{i=3}^{1983}a_i,$$ but I couldn't found the value of $d$.

Can someone help me?

Thanks for attention!

Comment: What coefficients are you taking the gcd of?

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1854528/338156